# How to create a space in Tarantool?

Tags: lua, tarantool

I've started Tarantool and have called `box.cfg{}` for the first configuring.

The next step: I want to create a space in Tarantool.
I read the documentation but I didn't quite understand everything.

How I should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create it via Box API:

```lua
box.schema.sequence.create('user_seq', { if_not_exists = true })
box.schema.create_space('users', { if_not_exists = true, format={
    { name = 'id', type = 'unsigned'},
    { name = 'name', type = 'string'}, 
    { name = 'age', type = 'unsigned'}} 
})
box.space.users:create_index('pk', { parts = { 'id' }, if_not_exists = true })
```

With `if_not_exists`, tarantool won't try to create space if it already exists.

Creating the index is mandatory because Tarantool doesn't allow you to insert data in space without any indexes.

After creating the space, you can insert and select data:

```lua
box.space.users:insert({ box.sequence.user_seq:next(), 'Artur Barsegyan', 24 })
box.space.users:get({1})
```

```yaml
---
- - [1, 'Artur Barsegyan']
...
```

You can read more [in the documentation.](https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/latest/reference/reference_lua/box_space/#lua-function.space_object.format)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create the sequence manually; just pass `true` and tarantool will create a sequence and even delete it when you drop the space. You can also skip the `parts` option as it defaults to `{1, 'unsigned'}`

```lua
box.space.users:create_index("pk", { if_not_exists = true, sequence = true })
```